# What are eclipse glasses made of?

Tags: optics, optical-materials, eclipse, glass

What is the principle of eclipse glasses?  Are they just high optical density plastic, or do they do something fancier?  Could I make my own by taping ND filters into cardboard?

I tried Googling around for answers to this, but just got a bunch of vendor links.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but a note of caution: The problem with all self-build solutions is that you can't easily judge how well they work outside the visible spectrum. So something that lets you comfortable stare into the sun might still transmit enough infrared light to cause serious damage. The safe option is to only use filter materials specifically designed for this purpose or to view a projected image of the sun (see e.g. [here](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/how-to-look-at-the-sun/)).

Comment: Also your retinas do not have pain receptors so even if you do not feel any damage it may still be occurring. A safer bet is a pinhole viewer.